# Primes and chirality: a definition and question in the context of tessellations for squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

These days I'm trying to research relations between prime numbers and the notion of chirality in the $xy$-plane. Wikipedia has the article [*Chirality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality).

I don't know if this relation or the problem for which I ask here is in the literature; please add a comment in such case.

**Definition.** In this post, I consider a definition ad hoc, defining as **admissible polygons** $P$ the connected regions in the $xy$-lattice that are arrangements of unit squares with $\text{area}(P)=p>3$ a prime number, and also by definition I consider that these polygons must have a chiral shape, that is these pieces are chirals. A tessellation of a connected region $R$ by means of admissible polygons is called an **admissible tessellation of** $R$ (in our problem $R=S$ will be a square $S$ in the $xy$-lattice).

(The rationale for previous definitions is that any polygonal representation of  the integers $1,2$ or $3$ aren't chirals, and on the other hand, again by definition one can consider that a given  composite integer can be represented as a rectangle or square $A\times B$, that isn't chiral polygon,  of sides $1<A\leq B$ in the $xy$-lattice as an arrangement of $n=A\cdot B$ unit squares. I emphasize with these brackets that these pieces will not be used in the tessellations in this post).

**Conjecture.** *There exists a constant* $N_0$ *such that every square* $S=N\times N$ *of side* $N$ *with* $N>N_0$ *can be represented by admissible polygons.*

> **Question.** I would like to know what work can be done to prove the veracity of the previous conjecture. **Many thanks.**

With admissible polygons it is easy get admissible tessellations for the square $4\times 4$, $5\times 5$, $6\times 6$ and $7\times 7$. We have the following obvious statement.

**Proposition.** *Given an admissible tessellation for the square* $S=N\times N$ *of* $N^2$ *unit squares, it is immediate to get an admissible tessellation for the square* $\hat{S}$ *of side* $2N$, *since this second square* $\hat{S}$ *admits the obvious decomposition into four squares* $S$.

Thus we must deal with squares $S=N\times N$ with $N>7$ an odd integer. Exploiting a specialization of a well-known identity $1+3+5=3^2$ I can tessellate the square $9\times 9$, because this square can be split as two copies of the square $(1+3)\times(1+3)$, plus the tessellated region corresponding to the square $5\times 5$ plus a region that can be tessellated with two admissible polygons with areas $7$ and $17$, being these chirals (I just emphasize it to provide details).

I think that the conjecture isn't obvious.

If you have problems getting it, and it is required, I can add in a figure some of the mentioned tessellations.

Comment: I've asked the same question in Mathematics Stack Exchange (post with identificator **4426156** on MSE), the post was deleted by the bot **Community** 17 days ago. An user provided a possible approach adding a comment in the deleted post.

Comment: I'm hard-pressed to see the relation between primality and chirality — it's true that the representation of a number as a product exhibits a specific achiral polyomino of that number, but it's easy to show that any $N$ whether prime or not has a chiral polyomino, and likewise easy to show that any $N\gt 3$ whether prime or not has a non-trivial achiral polyomino.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I add it ad hoc: I state a conjecture about primes **and** chirality. But I'm really interesting to continue what are the relations between primes and chirality. *If it was confussing now*, I'm agree because I'm trying to research possible relations: *I apologize it (I'm sorry)*, many thanks.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner many thnaks for your edit.

Comment: Also, Wikipedia has an article for *Arithmetic billiards*. Which I good like is to characterize chirality by means of some property of rays of light for certain rectangles (these rectangles representing prime numbers). This is an idea/speculation that I'm trying in my home (for me, prime numbers $p>2$ are similar than the capital letter *L*, that is the representation $1$ squared unit plus a rectangle of dimensions $1\times \varphi(p)$, where $\varphi(p)$ is the Euler totient function. But I don't know how motivate this idea/specualtion. Please feel free to explore it @StevenStadnicki

Comment: I've considered accept the more upvoted answer (both excellent answers were posted are due to the same professor), since I was asking about what work can be done about my question.

Comment: As soon I can, I'm going to offer a bounty to award the answers by the professor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I claim that there is an $N$ so that any rectangle with both sides at least $N$ can be decomposed into squares of sides $4,5,6$ and $7.$ If we show that, then the same applies squares of sides at least $N.$ I will show this for $N=1178.$ With a little more work that number could be decreased to $90.$ Although that is probably not optimal.

Let $a,b>0$ be relatively prime integers.

It is a result of [Frobenious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) that any integer $m\geq f(a,b)=ab-a-b+1$ can  be written in the form $m=as+bt$ with $s,t$ non-negative.

Using just $a\times a$ squares we can make a rectangle $a\times ab$ and using just $b \times b$ squares we can make a rectangle $b \times ab.$ Using those blocks we can make a rectangle $m \times ab$ for any $m\geq f(a,b)=ab-a-b+1$

Hence

- Using $4 \times 4$ and $5 \times 5$ squares we can make a rectangle $20 \times m$ for $m \geq f(4,5)=12.$

-Using $7 \times 7$ and $9 \times 9$ squares we can make a rectangle $63 \times m$ for $m \geq f(7,9)=48$

- Using all four sizes of squares we can make any rectangle $m \times n$ provided that $m \geq 48$ and $n \geq f(20,63)=1178.$

Sticking to squares and rectangles which can be decomposed into vertical rows each  of which itself can  be decomposed into horizontal columns of widths $4,5,6,7$ or $9$ (with the further restriction that each row uses only two widths) , is probably far from optimal. However, by the method above we can get

- Any row $2x \times 2y$ with $\min(2x,2y) \geq 12$ using $(a,b)=(4,6).$
- Any row $3x \times 3y$ with $\min(3x,3y) \geq 18$ using $(a,b)=(6,9).$
- Any row $ab \times m$ with $m \geq f(a,b)=ab-a-b+1$ for any of the eight relatively prime pairs drawn from $\{4,5,6,7,9\}$

Ignoring the first two types, we can get any rectangle $p \times q$ with with $p \in \{20,28,30,35,36,42,45,63\}$ and $q \geq 48.$

Combining those we can get any rectangle $r \times q$ with

$r \in \tiny{\{ 20, 28, 30, 35, 36, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 55, 56, 58, 60, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88\}}$ or $r \geq 90$ and $q \geq 48.$

Comment: Many thanks for your interesting and excellent answer, when I can I study it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different answer. You mention a particular interest in the $L$-$n$omino: a column of $n-1$ squares with one more square to the right on the bottom row. It has $4$-rotations and another $4$ obtained by rotation and reflection. The reflection might be called the $J$-$n$omino if one wanted to distinguish rotations from reflections (more often,  people do not.) It is true that $n-1=\varphi(n)$ for $n$-prime, but I don't see that you have motivated your focus on primality.

I will conjecture that if $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then using just the $L$-$m$omino and $L$-$n$omino you can tile any rectangle with both sides above some $N=N(m,n).$ In fact it might be that you could make do with just one orientation of each one in all but a few cases  (that is to say, $L$s but not $J$s). But then you would need a larger $N.$

In spite of your disinterest in tiling with rectangles, that is the key. Once you have a few rectangles you can use those as blocks to make others.

A coloring argument shows that any rectangle tiled by the $L$-tetromino uses an even number so has area a multiple of $8$. One easily finds how to get a $2\times 4$ and once you know to look for a $3\times 8$ you can find that too.

Aside: These two are called the **primes** of this tetromino because any other rectangle you can get can be made from them.

Claim: any rectangle with area a multiple of $8$ and shortest side at least $2$ can be tiled.

Sketch: if both sides are even, the $2 \times4$ alone is sufficient. If one side is odd, the other is a multiple of $8$. Stacking $k-1$ $2 \times 8$ and a single $3 \times 8$, you  can get $(2k+1) \times 8$

You can find a great deal of information about rectangle tilings at [this page](https://cflmath.com/Polyomino/rectifiable_data.html)

For the [$L$-pentomino](https://cflmath.com/Polyomino/l5_rect.html) one finds figures showing that the $2 \times 5$ and $7 \times  15$ can be tiled

Claim: Any rectangle with area a multiple of $5$ can be tiled as long as the one side is at least $15$ and the other at least $7.$

Using just the $2 \times 4$ and $2 \times 5$ you can get any $2 \times k$ except for $k=1,3,6,7,11$ and from that any even area rectangle with shortest side at least $12.$ One could probably improve that.

And using just those two $L$-ominos and the four prime rectangles mentioned, one can  get a $15 \times k$ and an $8 \times k$ for any $k \geq 7$ and hence also a $j \times k$ as long as $j \geq 98.$ Probably much better results are possible with a little work.

A link on that pentomino page leads to the claim (perhaps with  illustrations proving it) that using only the $L$ (and not the $J$) one can get $2\times 5, 13\times 55, 15\times 39, 17 \times 35$ and  $19 \times 25.$ Those are the one handed primes and with them you can get any rectangle with area a multiple of $5$ as long as the shortest side is at least $19$.

**A LITTLE MORE WORK**

We know how to get all squares which are of even side at least $4$ using just the $L$-teromino (no $J$-tetrominos)

Here are a $5 \times 5, 7 \times 7$ and $9 \times 9$. The solid rectangles are all  ones which we know we can fill. For  what it is worth, the $5 \times 5$ uses only $L$'s. I did not try to do that for the rest, it might not be hard. In fact the $9 \times 9$ has that property,

[image]

With four $3 \times 8$ rectangles around a $5 \times 5$ square we can make an $11 \times 11$ square.

Finally, if $k \geq 5$ is odd then we can make a a square of side $k+8$ by using a $k\times k$ in the upper left, and $8 \times 8$ on the lower right, a $k \times 8$ in the upper right and an $8 \times k$ in the lower left.

Comment: Many thanks you're a very very good mathematician. I'm editing a post in a different site, and I have not internet at home, when I can I study your answers.

Comment: Your added work is very nice and interesting, many thanks again.

Comment: Both answers are nice.